# User Control asp.net

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have a user control made of txtbox and drop downlist.The drop downlist is rendered if data is present otherwise txtbox is rendered. How do i write get{} and set{} methods for th user control for adding and retrieving data as well as for visible property.

Comment: how does the dropdownlist get data?

Comment: i have a property in my user control that populates ddl from array

Answer (score 0):

```
partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
  public bool VisibleInner {
    get { return Panel1.Visible; }
    set { Panel1.Visible = value ; }
  }

  private List<ControlData> _controlData;
  public List<ControlData> ControlData {
    get { return _controlData; }
    set { _controlData = value; }
  }

  protected void Page_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (_controlData != null && _controlData.Count > 0)
     {
        TextBox1.Visible = false;
        DropDownList1.Visible = true;
        DropDownList1.DataSource = _controlData;
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
     }
     else 
     {
        TextBox1.Visible = true;
        DropDownList1.Visible = false;
     }
  }
}
public class ControlData
{
   public string Value { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
}
```